# Query contacts list of BotFramework Bot

Tags: python, botframework

I'm trying to create bot for Skype. I have created my own skype bot (on botframework.com) and its server and they can communicate with each other. However when I stop my server they will lost the information about the bot's contacts.

Is there any REST API call to botframework to get the list of the contacts of the bot?

Comment: This is not currently a feature in bot framework

Comment: Then how do you know the contacts of a Bot???

Comment: That would be specific to a channel, in this case skype.  So that is handled on the channel side not within bot framework.

Comment: Ok, then how do you do that????